# Unable to refresh imageView

Tags: java, android

So I have tried everything I could to Refresh my imageView contents with imagrView.setImageURI(URI) and it works when I do it the first time. But when I store the Uri of the new image and revisit the activity and call this method again ( for the stored URI) it shows a blank white screen. I have also checked that the Uri is not null and also tried invalidate(), postinvalidate()...etc all solutions I could find on the web. Any idea why it's working when I immediately set it but not later? Do I need to set permissions for that?

Comment: setImageURI(URI) only works with local images.  One possibility is that you are using a local URI for the first call and a remote one for the second call. 
 What are the values of URI?

Comment: No I am just storing the URL inside a static variable. The photo is picked from my image gallery. When I return to that acitivity and try to re access that Uri it doesn't work, even though it worked the first time around